# asus bios utility: the system cannot find any bootable devices

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb, uefi, bios

#### Context

My Asus laptop had Endless OS installed and I wanted to switch to Ubuntu 18. So I followed the instructions to install Ubuntu in the machine, erasing all of the Endless OS (no dual boot). I was able to get to the bios, changed the boot order and installed Ubuntu (it went through a complete install).

#### The Problem

When I restarted, the computer went directly to the bios utility screen, which had no boot options and showed me a **"the system cannot find any bootable devices"** message.

I'm able to access Ubuntu through the "try Ubuntu" option on install when the USB is left on (so my computer can indeed boot from USB). The problem is booting without an USB.

#### What I already have tried (and found):

- Information is overall disperse and most of it is related to windows. There are a lot of dead threads and I couldn't find anything similar in askUbuntu.
- Most of the posts / videos direct me to setting UEFI, but the bios utility doesn't seem to have such an option.
- All possible combinations of CSM support and Fast Boot

None of these have worked.

#### Questions:

How can I get a list of bootable devices?

How can I get my machine to boot again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved the problem and wanted to share here:

1. Launch CSM support (under boot menu): must be **enabled**.
2. SATA configuration (under advanced menu): muest be in **AHCI** mode.

Comment: #1 is obviously wrong. The problem is you don't understand UEFI requirements: GPT and an EFI Partition. Ubuntu can be installed in UEFI mode in a MBR drive but uf doing it from scratch there's absolutely no reason nit to use GPT. Tje second is mandatory.

Comment: What you mean is it would have worked if I only did #2? I'll appreciate if you can explain it to me in a little more detail, I'm not really familiar with this, and just followed what I saw in another forum.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean, that and of course starting with  GPT drive -> The automatic installation would take care of creating the required EFI partition, if manually then you'd have to create it yourself.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Should I go and undo #1, or it'll be OK if left as it is now?

Comment: If you "undo" it now Ubuntu won' t boot. But it's a good idea to edit and remove that part for the sake of future users ;)

Comment: Reporting from 2021, I created an account just to confirm these steps worked for me. I'd moved my 9 year old SSD/HDs to a new asus motherboard, where they were recognized but couldn't be booted from. Following these two changes fixed the issue entirely, and now I can boot my old operating system. Thanks PavoDive, you rock :)

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me, launch CSM support was disabled and grayed out. I tried disabling fast boot and after restarting, ubuntu booted up just fine! Thought I would share here in case other asus laptop users run into the same problem.